# Need to install php5.4 on ubuntu 12.04 LTS precise

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, phing

I am using following [instruction](http://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/) to install latest php on unbutu instance:

Add to /etc/apt/source.list

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org stable all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org stable all
```

Update apt-key

```
sudo wget -q  http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
sudo apt-key add dotdeb.gpg
sudo apt-get update
```

install apache2 + php

```
`sudo apt-get install -y apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5`
```

Output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: libxml2 (>= 2.8.0) but 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4 is to be installed
                       Recommends: php5-cli but it is not going to be installed
```

I need a stable way to install latest php. Previously I was using ppa and decided to not use it bcz of security

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
```

I wonder if there is a better way to setup latest php+apache2+mysql , I have to script the process to automate the installation and invoke it through build script

Side note/problem background:

I am using Phing ssh task to invoke the script to setup php+apache2+mysql, which break with `add-apt-repository` command for weird reason

Reference:

```
 <ssh host="${deploy.host}"
             username="${deploy.user}"
             privkeyfile="${deploy.pem}"
             pubkeyfile="${deploy.pub}"
             command="${ssh_command}"
             display="false"
             property="ssh.output"
             failonerror="true"
                />
```

`ssh_command` where I invoke the script

Further tests:
 `sudo apt-get install -y   apache2 php5 php5-cli libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql php5-gd  php5-memcache php5-mcrypt php5-xsl`

Output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: libxml2 (>= 2.8.0) but 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4 is to be installed
 php5-cli : Depends: libxml2 (>= 2.8.0) but 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4 is to be installed
            Depends: libedit2 (>= 2.11-20080614-4) but 2.11-20080614-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Have you tried installing `php5-cli`? (e.g., `sudo apt-get install php5-cli`.)

Comment: yes which adds another dependency into list

Comment: Did you do it from the command line without the `-y` flag? If so, try `sudo apt-get -f install` as well. The `-f` means fix. It will attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place, allowing apt-get to omit any packages in order to deduce a likely solution.

Comment: I don't understand one thing, you said you need 5.4 and then you said you need the latest stable, the current stable as of today is 5.6.3.

Which one do you need?

Comment: I need at-least 5.4, do you suggest any changes in source.list for that ?

Comment: please check with additional info ,after adding php5-cli

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation.

The place where I was working was using an old version on PHP (5.3.8).

I installed the latest version of Ubuntu in my desktop and then I realised that downgrading from 5.5 to 5.3 was almost impossible, too many dependencies to handle, the best solution I could find was to use an "all-in-one" package like XAMPP.

Even though I hate those solutions I changed my mind after a couple of hours, it did exactly what it was supposed to do, I didn't have to do any sorcery in the package manager or alter any configuration files.

[Here is the XAMPP version I would use in your case (1.8.2-3 version - PHP 5.4 based)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Linux/1.8.2/)

It contains

> PHP 5.4.22
>
> MySQL 5.5.34
>
> Apache 2.4.7
>
> phpMyAdmin 4.0.9

More info: [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/news-article-232017.html) and [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

Comment: its not development machine,instead I need to setup this on Amazon EC2 machine. I think I have found another option , use one of the higher versions of the ubuntu ,probably that is the best stable/secure way .